# How do I make UITextView use its parent's undoManager instead of its own

Tags: uikit, nsundomanager

I have a `UIViewController` that has a `PKCanvasView` and several `UITextViews` as its subviews. I need to unify all of these views' undo managers, so I can control them as a single undo stack from my view controller.

I can already do this with `PKCanvasView`, it seems that by default it uses the undoManager of its parent view, so I can do things like manually register undo events from my view controller, and undo/redo them from my `PKCanvasView`'s `PKToolPicker`'s undo/redo buttons, which is fantastic.

Regrettably, this doesn't seem to be the case with `UITextView`, each one seems to have its own undoManager, and it doesn't connect in any way with my control view's undo manager, which is a big problem.

Anyone know how can I force a `UITextViews` to use a view controller's undo manager?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to create an extension UITextView and set the undoManager of the UITextView instance to its parent's undoManager:

```
extension UITextView {
    
    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        self.undoManager = (self.superview as? UIViewController)?.undoManager
    }
}
```

The awakeFromNib method is a UIView initializer that gets called after it has been loaded from a xib or storyboard. This will ensure that every instance of UITextView in your view controller will have its undoManager set to the view controller's undoManager.